# Retrieving an Oracle timestamp using Python's Win32 ODBC module

Tags: python, oracle, ora-00932

Given an Oracle table created using the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Log(WhenAdded TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE);
```

Using the Python ODBC module from its [Win32 extensions](http://www.python.org/download/windows/) (from the win32all package), I tried the following:

```
import dbi, odbc

connection = odbc.odbc("Driver=Oracle in OraHome92;Dbq=SERVER;Uid=USER;Pwd=PASSWD")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT WhenAdded FROM Log")

results = cursor.fetchall()
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    results = cursor.fetchall()
dbi.operation-error: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s 
in FETCH
```

The other data types I've tried (VARCHAR2, BLOB) do not cause this problem. Is there a way of retrieving timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in the Oracle ODBC driver. Basically, the Oracle ODBC driver does not support the `TIMESTAMP WITH (LOCAL) TIME ZONE` data types, only the `TIMESTAMP` data type. As you have discovered, one workaround is in fact to use the `TO_CHAR` method.

In your example you are not actually reading the time zone information. If you have control of the table you could convert it to a straight `TIMESTAMP` column. If you don't have control over the table, another solution may be to create a view that converts from `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` to `TIMESTAMP` via a string - sorry, I don't know if there is a way to convert directly from `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` to `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this, that I hope can be bettered, is to use Oracle to explicitly convert the TIMESTAMP into a string:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT TO_CHAR(WhenAdded, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SSAM') FROM Log")
```

This works, but isn't portable. I'd like to use the same Python script against a SQL Server database, so an Oracle-specific solution (such as TO_CHAR) won't work.